# Animated GIF while loading page does not animate

Tags: javascript, onload, gif, animated

I have a page which is being generated serverside using asp.net (C#). It takes a while for the page to load as it has up to 100 iframes. I want to show a "please wait" animated gif while the page is loading, so I have the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #blackout
    {
       filter:alpha(opacity=70); 
       -moz-opacity:0.7; 
       opacity:0.7; 
       position:absolute;
       background-color:#222233;
       z-index:50; 
       left:0px;
       top:0px;
       right:0px;
       bottom:0px;
       width:102%;
       height:102%;
    }
    #loading
    {
       filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
       -moz-opacity:1; 
       opacity:1; 
        position:fixed;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#EEEEEE;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        margin-top:-55px;
        margin-left:-75px;
        width:150px;
        height:75px;
        z-index:100; 
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility='hidden';document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none';document.getElementById('blackout').style.visibility='hidden';document.getElementById('blackout').style.display='none';">
    <div id="blackout">
        <div id="loading"><img id="loadinggif" src="graphics/loading.gif" alt="" style="margin-top:12px; "/><br />Please wait...</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            document.getElementById('loadinggif').src = 'graphics/loading.gif';
        </script>
    </div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
```

So the problem is that the loading gif is not moving. I have tried to use

```
setTimeout("document.getElementById('loadinggif').src = 'graphics/loading.gif'", 100);
```

too, and it made the gif move "a little", but not as intended.

How can I make it animate un-interrupted during load?

Answer (score 12):

old question, but posting this for fellow googlers:

Spin.js DOES WORK for this use case:
http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar problem and found a pretty easy solution - my markup looks somewhat like this:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.className = '_indicator'; doSomething();">Foo</a></li>
```

The CSS-Class is assigning an animated gif to the background of that li-element. This works great, but the image is not moving. Applying "focus()" to the li afterwards solves this:

```
<li><a .. onclick="this.parentNode.className = "_indicator'; this.parentNode.focus(); ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('loadinggif').src = 'graphics/loading.gif'}, 100);
```

include it as a function and watch your quotations

You may want to do it like this. Declare the src in the html but have it hidden, then perform:

```
setTimeout(
  function() {
    document.getElementById('loadinggif').style.display ='block';
       setTimeout(
          function() {
             document.getElementById('loadinggif').style.display = 'none';
          }, 100);
  }, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first solution gives the same result as

`code`setTimeout("document.getElementById('loadinggif').src = 'graphics/loading.gif'", 100); 

It works in firefox but in IE it only moves a notch now and then. Second suggestion just shows no gif at all.

I know it is an IE problem, but I was wondering if there is a way to make it animate all the time in IE like it does in FF.

Comment: I am using this one:

[http://epc.inet4.com/images/dialog/loading.gif](http://epc.inet4.com/images/dialog/loading.gif)

Comment: The only thing i can think of is that changing the src dynamically or having the element start off with display = none is that it has to load the image when you execute this command.. perhaps IE is buggy with registering the image after all has rendered? try doing visiblity = hidden and then making it visible, that will have the gif loaded with the render

Comment: After some testing, it seems that IE is just too busy with other things to care about animating gifs while loading content :) 

So I'll just show a non-animated hourglass, ha ha...

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I don't think there is any solution.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `setInterval()`? setTimeout only runs once while setInterval is continuously run until stopped.

```
var x = setInterval(document.getElementById('loadinggif').src = 'graphics/loading.gif', 100);
```

...  when done loading ....

```
clearInterval(x);
```

although, now that i think about it, all your code is doing is setting the image source to the animated gif.  the real problem is that IE seems to be "locked" when doing a lot of jScript processing in the background and doesn't run animations.

you could try to have all the gif's in the animation as seperate files and then use the interfval function to change the src to mimic the same animation.

maybe somehting like this...

```
//global var
var imgIndex = 0;



var x = setInterval(changeImgSrc, 100);
```

...  when done loading ....

```
clearInterval(x);


function changeImgSrc(i){
document.getElementById('loadinggif').src = 'graphics/loading' + (imgIndex++) + '.gif'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set backgroung CSS property to contain the gif image u want to display during the animation.

```
background: rgba( 198, 226, 255, .5 ) 
                url('images/15.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
```

.5 indicates the opacity;
in URL part you can give relative or complete URL for your gif image.